# Trivial texture load in andengine

Tags: android, load, textures, andengine

In andngine , I defined a texture, using the following line code:

```
private Texture mTexture;
```

And here is my onLoadResource function:

```
   public void onLoadResources() {
this.mTexture = new Texture(64, 64,
TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
}
```

but this code gives an error, because the only constructor in "import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.Texture" class has the following signature:

```
public Texture(final PixelFormat pPixelFormat, final TextureOptions pTextureOptions, final ITextureStateListener pTextureStateListener);
```

Would you please help me what to do? Most tutorials, used something like this:

```
new Texture(64, 64,
TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
```

But mine, does not work. Your help would be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that a few months ago a bunch of the functionality of the original `Texture` class was moved to [`BitmapTextureAtlas`](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/opengl/texture/atlas/bitmap/BitmapTextureAtlas.java). You should be able to call the constructor of that with the same width, height and `TextureOptions` parameters - or any of the other variants of your liking.

```
BitmapTextureAtlas(int pWidth, int pHeight) 
BitmapTextureAtlas(int pWidth, int pHeight, BitmapTextureAtlas.BitmapTextureFormat pBitmapTextureFormat)            
BitmapTextureAtlas(int pWidth, int pHeight, BitmapTextureAtlas.BitmapTextureFormat pBitmapTextureFormat, ITextureAtlas.ITextureAtlasStateListener<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource> pTextureAtlasStateListener)
BitmapTextureAtlas(int pWidth, int pHeight, BitmapTextureAtlas.BitmapTextureFormat pBitmapTextureFormat, TextureOptions pTextureOptions)
BitmapTextureAtlas(int pWidth, int pHeight, BitmapTextureAtlas.BitmapTextureFormat pBitmapTextureFormat, TextureOptions pTextureOptions, ITextureAtlas.ITextureAtlasStateListener<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource> pTextureAtlasStateListener)        
BitmapTextureAtlas(int pWidth, int pHeight, ITextureAtlas.ITextureAtlasStateListener<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource> pTextureAtlasStateListener) 
BitmapTextureAtlas(int pWidth, int pHeight, TextureOptions pTextureOptions) 
BitmapTextureAtlas(int pWidth, int pHeight, TextureOptions pTextureOptions, ITextureAtlas.ITextureAtlasStateListener<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource> pTextureAtlasStateListener)
```

There's also a code example in [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863212/andengine-apply-force).